# How to shadow singleton with Robolectic?

Tags: android, singleton, robolectric

I have such a singleton:

```
public class SingletonA{

      private SingletonA instance = null;

      private SingletonA(){
      }

      public static SingletonA getInstance(){
          return instance ;
      }

      public static void init(){
           System.loadLibrary("alib");
           instance = new SingletonA();
      }

      ......
      other methods
}
```

As you can see, before use it , I have to call SingletonA.init().But Robolectric can not load **.so** file. I want to write a ShadowSingletonA to replace it, but don't know how to do.Because variable **instance** is private. Can any one help? Besides, class SingletonA is from some third part library so I can not do any modification to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another common way to deal with you dependencies abstract them to make them interchangeable and testable.

So assume you have great library with next API:

```
class LibraryName {
    public static SomeSinglethon getInstance();
}
```

First, create the abstraction:

```
public class LibraryGenericPurpose {
   public void doSomeThing(@NonNull String nameOfThing) {
      LibraryName.getInstance().doSomething(new Event(nameOfThing));
   }
}
```

First note that the method is not static, so you have to add an extra dependency in all places where you were just calling static methods from the library. Sometimes it is handy also to have the interface for such thing.

And now you change a place where you use it from:

```
class SomeClass {
    public void someMethod() {
        LibraryName.getInstance().doSomething(new Event(nameOfThing));
    }
}
```

to:

```
class SomeClass {
    @NonNull private LibraryGenericPurpose library;

    public SomeClass(@NonNull LibraryGenericPurpose library) {
        this.library = library;
    }

    public void someMethod() {
        library.doSomeThing("Great!");
    }
}
```

And if you don't have control over the class life cycle as `Activity` or `Fragment` then you have to learn new ways how to inject dependencies there.

Finally, in the tests, you don't need to use Robolectric for `SomeClass` at all. And quite often these classes like `LibraryGenericPurpose` are not testable on JVM (even with **Robolectric**) and quite hard or impossible to test in instrumental tests.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach to make it testable. 
We mostly initialize third-party libraries in the application class. In a way:

```
public class MyApplication {
  public void onCreate() {
     initSomeLibrary();
  }

  @VisibleForTests
  @RestrictTo(RestrictTo.Scope.TESTS)
  protected void initSomeLibrary() {
     SomeLibrary.init(this);
  }
}
```

Robolectric will always try to load the app that is specified in your manifest unless you were done:

1. [Add `@Config` where you defined another app class name](http://robolectric.org/configuring/)
2. [You put in test folder in the same package app class that has name Test](http://robolectric.org/custom-test-runner/)

So in both cases, you have to create custom application app. Historically the first option was available earlier, so I stick to it. However, it requires knowledge about Robolectric, so I put my test application class to `@Config` section now (so **Test** is not required anymore):

```
public class TestMyApplication {
    protected void initSomeLibrary() {
      //nothing to do
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I have already used custom application in my UT cases to avoid loading ".so" files. But recently,I have got a class named EZOpenSDK in singleton mode which run **System.loadLibrary()** in its constructor. This forbits me to create an instance of this class in UT. So I want to create a ShadowEZOpenSDK to replace it. But yet I don't know how to deal with method **public static EZOpenSDK  getInstance()** in my ShadowEZOpenSDK.

Comment: Then I will write another answer :)

Comment: That's very kind of you.